# Different colors for the selected item and the list of items in the dropdown of a Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-theme

I have a `TextView` that sets the color for a `Spinner`. The problem is I want to have different colors for the selected single item and the items that are in the dropdown. I read that this solves the problem:

```
<style name="Theme.NoTitleBar.WithColoredSpinners"  
parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem.DropDownItem</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerItem.DropDownItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
```

but I don't want to apply this theme in my manifest file(there is some constraint due to which I cannot do that). Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you cann't apply this styles in a theme, apply them in the layout files for that items that you wont to style